# Context broker: unregister context

Tags: fiware-orion

I need to delete context via NGSI9 API in Context Broker but I cannot find anything related in the documentation. How could I do it?

If it's no possible, is there any recommendation (e.g.: by setting duration to 0)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Orion User Manual](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Updating_registrations):

> Surprisingly, there is no way in NGSI to cancel a registration. A
>   workaround is to update it with a non-existing entity and duration 0,
>   but in order to do an actual delete you will need to remove the
>   registration from the database (check [the administration manual about
>   managing database](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Database_administration)).

Once expired, if you have access to Orion DB, you can use the procedure described in [Deleting expired documents](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Deleting_expired_documents) to permanently remove the registration from database.